# Determining formula for PayPal deposit?

Tags: paypal

I am developing an e-commerce website that let's people fund their accounts via PayPal.  In order to not taking hits on deposits every day, we have to charge PayPals fees to the customer for their deposit.  PayPal takes 2.9 + .30.  However, if we charged 2.9 + .30 then PayPal takes their fees on the new total.

So on 100$ we would charge 103.20 to deposit 100, but PayPal now takes 103.29 and we take a .09c hit on that deposit.

How could I create a forumla to be left with exactly their deposit amount after PayPal takes 2.9 + .30?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing up **Addition** of a percentage with **Subtraction** of a percentage:

IMHO the correct way to look at this ist, to say PayPal leaves you with 97.1% of the original balance -0.3

so the correct value is **103.28661174...**, at which I arrived with `(100/0.971)+0.3`

Trying this out: From the 103.28661174 PayPal will take 0.30, leaving 102.98661174, from which it will take 2.9%, or 2.98661174..., leaving you with 100

Comment: yes but your numbers change every single time the amount changes...  the website thefeecalculator.com is using the exact formula im looking for... i just dono what it is lol

Comment: Ofcourse they do! If you want a deposit of $200 you need `(200/0.971)+0.3` or as a formula: `Brutto(x)=(x/0.971)+0.3`

Comment: I just checked my formula against http://thefeecalculator.com with amounts of 100,200 and 700 $ and they were identical.

Comment: so the formula is (Value/0.971)+0.3 ?  THANKS!

Comment: As I said in my previous comment: Yes, this is the formula. You arrive at it by taking your original value, dividing by 0.971 to reflect, that PayPal leaves you only 97.1% and adding 0.3 which is the PayPal fixed transaction fee

Comment: You can show this, by accepting my answer (Green checkmark). A high rate of accepted answers will also help to motivate others on this site to answer your future questions.